# How do I recover lost data on a damaged SD card that was encrypted by my tablet?

Tags: data-recovery, encryption

I encrypted my 64 GB SD card using my Samsung Galaxy tab 3. I don't know what happened to my SD card but when I turn on the tablet, instead of allowing me to use the card, I get the following messages...  >preparing SD card - checking for errors  >SD card encryption - encrypting SD card  >SD card safe to remove - you can safely remove SD card. Any idea what"s wrong and how to fix?

Comment: That's why you should not encrypt anything unless its extremely private. Its on every system there if anything goes wrong you loose all the valuable data.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, your issue sounds weird. Your SD Card is 1) Damaged and 2) Encrypted, yet you want to recover data from it?

If 1) is true, then whether 2) or not, you can't access the card. If 1) is false, and 2) is true, then, generally, you should be prompted to enter a password to use in decrypting the card. If that prompt doesn't come up, then you likely might need to use the exact device used in encrypting the SD card to decrypt. If that device isn't available, you might need a similar one to use to try.